# How do you animate static mesh in Unity?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

Can Unity animate static meshes like animating UV?
If this is not integrated, is there an Asset you have enjoyed using for this?

Comment: Can you show an example of the effect you wish to achieve?

Comment: @Doh09 Abzu's technical art presentation at GDC several years ago. It's on YouTube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animating UV as in animated textures in the material yes you can do, no its not 'out of the box' but is simple to implament. There are various options available best to look at a few and see what suits e.g. you can create a shader that does this, you could also update the UV offset from script, etc.
https://forum.unity.com/threads/simple-animated-uvs.24452/
The link above is from the Unity Community on a similar subject.

Animating in the litteral since e.g. moving, yes and no ... yes you can, no you should not.

Static ... first off this applies to several aspects of Unity, I am assuming you just ticked the 'Static' tick box in which case its static in all of them including lighting and physics in which case moving the mesh will cause you problems.

Comment: In Abzu's technical art presentation at GDC few years ago I've seen GiantSquid done static mesh animating as if blendshapes. From your saying I'm assuming Unity doesn't have that like UE does for Abzu. I was hoping if there was at least an asset in the asset store for this, but couldn't get anywhere searching.

Comment: 'Static' in Unity means it doesn't move, this is used for baking lighting, occlusion, etc. That is 'Static' doesn't describe rather or not there are joints, rather its a skinned mesh or not, etc. it simply means the thing wont move in the games space.


Why do you need it to be static again?
Or did you mean static as in the mesh doesn't have joints and bones?

Comment: The latter of your guess is correct. In animation, when it's the mesh being animated not the skeleton it's often called static mesh animation, just like how it's called static mesh animation in UE as I've mentioned.

Comment: Ah in which case no, in Unity there are 2 different types of meshes.

Skinedmesh ... these can be animated
Mesh ... these are rigid/not animated

Converting between the two I suppose is possible but not without code and I dont know any tools off hand that would do that.

Comment: [Not a fan of this comment system]
 
To add to that ... you can animate anything in unity that is you can make it move around via key frames but deforming a mesh requires it to be a skinnedmesh with joints or for you to use some code to 'skin' it ... or a 3rd party tool.

Comment: Hey, I thank you enough for trying to help out. And in fact, I overlooked skinedmesh. Thanks, I'll look into how I can fiddle around with skinned mesh to achieve this.

Comment: Did a search my self and found a tool that combines mesh objects into a skinned mesh
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IlRlYNsHgmE

might get you started

Comment: Just about found it, too. Thanks. I got what what  I needed.