# Unity 2D - animated background

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, background, sprite, unityscript

I'm working on a game with free pixel adventure sprites. The GIF  below is a level that the sprite creator put, and I have no idea how to create such a background in Unity (repeat with go down animation).

Background sprite Also added in the end of this post.

[image: Game]

[image: Sprite]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you animate static mesh in Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48860640/how-do-you-animate-static-mesh-in-unity)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this same effect with just a shader too, make a big quad put that texture mode to repeat and change the uv coords with time, if u want vertical movement add the uv's y component with time it will just achieve the same effect much optimized ..

if u want i will provide u with a basic shader that does that :)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you should switch the wrap mode of the sprite to repeat, add that sprite to the material of the 3d object background, and add a script to the background that has access to the mesh. Here is a video that addresses the issue. It is 3 min long. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4r4Ul6QrFg.
Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).